# TortoiseHG Workbench filter include working directory

Tags: filter, toolbar, tortoisehg

I'm trying to reduce the noise in tortoiseHG workbench with the filter toolbar.

"head() & !closed()" gets me 90% there, I see the heads of active branches.

but I also want to see the working directory to see what branch I'm on.

is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

`head() & !closed() + .` just add active changeset to list of heads (*if* it isn't one of head)

Direct parent

[image: Parent]

Far ancestor

[image: Far]